# Executing local script/command on remote server

Tags: linux, unix, ssh, gnu

I have a command that I want to run on machine B from machine A. If I run the command on machine B locally, it works fine.

Here is the command:

```
for n in `find /data1/ -name 'ini*.ext'` ; do  echo cp $n "`dirname $n `/` basename $n 
.ext`"; done
```

From machine A, I issue this command

```
ssh user@machineB  for n in `find /data1/ -name 'ini*jsem'` ; do  echo cp $n "`dirname $n `/` basename $n .jsem`"; done
```

But I get error `syntax error near unexpected token do`

What is wrong? I think it has something to do with double quotes, single quotes, semi colon because executing command  `ssh user@machineB ls` works fine. So not issue of authentication or something else.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your code in a script, `myScript.sh` and execute it, just like ls: `ssh user@machineB myScript.sh`

Comment: Just when I was about to delete the question, I did it exactly this way. Thank you.Accepted the answer.